# Constructors and Constructors Overloading

Tags: java, oop, constructor, constructor-overloading

Can any one explain?

When we are overloading a constructor with different parameters one having data type object and other having data type string, and when we are creating the object of this class with providing input parameter as null it is calling  the constructor with string as input parameter but not the constructor having input parameter as Object. Since Object is the super class of String, can any one tell me why it is calling constructor with input parameter string?

```
Class A
{
  public A(Object o)
   {
     System.out.println("Object Drawn");
   }
   public A (String o)
   {
     System.out.println("String Drawn");
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
   new A(null);
   }
 }
```

Output:- String Drawn

Comment: This is either a C++ question or a Java question, but not both.  It looks to be Java, so why the `c++` tag?

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the C++ flag.

Comment: I don't see how the language matters given the answer is the same.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That is obvious.  As someone experienced with C++, I can't confidently answer a question about Java, so the tag wastes the time of C++-only people like me; and no-one coming here looking for the C++ answer *who didn't already know the two languages behave the same way in this respect* could draw any useful information about C++ from it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I am surprised you couldn't answer what the equivalent in C++ might do as the Java is unreadable. ;)

Comment: @j_random_hacker If you could provide the answer for C++ I don't see why you haven't done so.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the answer is **not** the same in c++. Since `A` us being constructed with `null`, the only possible C++ equivalent is to make the constructors take a pointer to `Object` and `String`, and calling `A(nullptr)` would result in a compilation error due to an ambiguous overload.

Comment: @EJP the answer in C++ is that there is simply no equivalent to the java code above.

Comment: @juanchopanza The syntax required to make the question meaningful is obviously different, but the answer in C++, or indeed any other language that has overloaded methods, is the same as the answer in Java: the most specific overload is called, for the reason Peter Lawrey gave in his answer.

Comment: @EJP: I didn't argue with Peter Lawrey's "equivalence" assertion when I should have: as juanchopanza observes, and http://ideone.com/mBdC9 demonstrates, the answer is that the C++ equivalent will not compile, so the two languages are in fact *not equivalent* here.

Answer (score 4):

It always calls the most specific matching method or constructor.  If it didn't you would always call `Object` and overloading it would be pointless.

This approach is using in Java and C++

Comment: Is it so because the null string "" is more appropriate?
And is there something as a null object?

Comment: If you use `""` it is definitely an empty String. If you use `null` is can be either a String or an Object.  The term "null string" and "null object" is just confusing and there is no standard value for this.